# Attempting to change the value of a specific cell in my worksheet using VBA is failing

Tags: excel, vba

My objective is trying to traverse a group of cells in an Excel 2010 worksheet and within this same worksheet change the value of another cell.  Here is my attempt at trying to do that with VBA.  When I try and change the cell where moCost is defined I get a "Type MisMatch" error.

Also, I am assuming that when I change (Using the Worksheet Change event) the value in the cells of my worksheet for either of the variables I used the Set that it will change the value of the moCostAfford si that correct?  Just trying to confirm.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I4:K42")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim moCost As Range, moCostAmount As Range, moCostManual As Range, moCostAfford As ValueChange
    Dim cell As Range, affordabilityRowValues As Range
    Set moCost = Range("A13")
    Set moCostAmt = Range("B13")
    Set moCostManual = Range("B14")
    Set moCostAfford = Range("C13")
    Set affordabilityRowValues = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I4:K42"))
    For Each cell In affordabilityRowValues.Cells
        If cell.Offset(0, 1) = moCost And cell.Offset(0, 2) = moCostAmount And moCostManual = "0" Then
            moCostAfford = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        Else
            moCostAfford = moCostAmount
        End If
    Next
    Set affordabilityRowValues = Nothing
    Set moCostAfford = Nothing
    Set moCostManual = Nothing
    Set moCostAmount = Nothing
    Set moCost = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Exit Sub    

haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image: ExcelSpreadsheet]

Comment: Fist things first, type Option Explicit at the top of your module. this will warn you about any variables you haven't declared or have misspelt (Hint: there's at least one). After that, check the variable type and the property you are using for moCostAffordValue. I have never used the type ValueChange but it appears Value is not a valid property for that type or is expecting an argument.

Comment: `moCost` is a range but you are not setting a range in the line `Set moCost = Application.Cells.Value("A13")` It would look like `Set moCost = Range("A13")` or if `A13` has a cell address then `Set moCost = Range(Range("A13").Value)` Similarly for others

Comment: Thanks, guys!  I'll make these corrections and hopefully eliminate the error.

Comment: @Melinda: What you have done is correct. But one small change, Use Set moCost = Application.Cells(13, 1). Instead of specifying Range A13 use row, column format.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot simply use `=VLOOKUP(A13, J4:K42, 2, FALSE)` in B13?

Comment: I've not used VLOOKUP.  I guess I can try that.  I appreciate your response.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The range object assignments are malformed, but beyond that they are are also assigned every time anything in your worksheet changes before you make any decision to even use then. It's also good practise to set them to nothing before you exit your sub. Here is a pared down version that you might wish to expand upon.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I4:K42")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim moCost As Range, moCostManual As Range, moCostAfford As ValueChange
        Dim cell As Range, affordabilityRowValues As Range
        Set moCost = Range("A13")
        Set moCostManual = Range("B14")
        Set moCostAfford = Range("C13")
        Set affordabilityRowValues = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I4:K42"))
        For Each cell In affordabilityRowValues.Cells
            If cell.Offset(0, 1) = moCost And cell.Offset(0, 2) = moCostManual Then
                moCostAfford = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        Next
        Set affordabilityRowValues = Nothing
        Set moCostAfford = Nothing
        Set moCostManual = Nothing
        Set moCost = Nothing
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
Exit Sub

haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

With the large number of cells you are working with, I would probably switch to working with variables that store the cell values rather than the cells themselves. Better yet, work directly with the cells rather than variables with long names. If you simply work better with names than cell range references, consider taking the time to create a series of *named ranges* in `Formulas ► Name Manager`. If you assign *moCost* to A13 then your code can use `Range("moCost")` rather than declaring a variable and setting it to A13.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info.  I really appreciate your time and help.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, unfortunately that did not work me.  I modified in my original post the code to match your post above. Just an FYI, I had to enter another argument in my IF statement as I forgot one. I also posted a JPG file so that you can see what I'm doing. In summary what I'm trying to do is I am having to enter a value in B14 to a dollar figure and then if the values in A13, B13 and B14 match a ROW in the affordabilityRowValues then change the value in C13 to that value.  Hope that makes sense.